# Which collation is preferred when sorting is not required?

Tags: php, mysql, database, collation

I have a table e.g.:

```
create table T1(Id int primary key auto_increment, Value text)
```

`Value` is used to store "textual" data but rows are **never sorted** according to the `Value` column.

Which collation should be prefered for `Value`?

Would `utf8mb4_bin` be a better choice or `utf8mb4_general_ci`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks fine. I *certainly* wouldn't use a case-insensitive collation if it wasn't needed (as per your case) since it *may* result in slower queries (though I doubt it would be used for non-textual fields anyway).

You should keep in mind, however, that collation is not just for sorting, but for *selection* as well (e.g., the `where` clause). If you're only going to retrieve rows based on columns other than `Value`, that shouldn't matter.

In any case, I'm actually not a big fan of case-insensitive collations being done by the database itself, since I'd rather keep the database running as blindingly fast as possible, and use my *own* methods to handle case issues (such as an extra indexed column holding lower-cased last names, and updated with insert/update triggers to maintain consistency with the rest of the row).

Basically, I'm a Luddite :-) but nobody ever complains about how *big* their databases are, only about how *slow.*

Comment: When you say that you are a Luddite, do you mean that in the old days that is how it gets done? Even at the industry-standard level?